# Hyperref boxes around links ARE MISSING in TeXShop

Tags: hyperref, mactex, texshop, links

I was using TeXShop 2.26 on Mac OS 10.5.8. Switched today to TeXShop 3.36 on Mac OS 10.9.4. In all my LaTeX files, the `hyperref` red green cyan boxes around the links don't show up anymore. The links work, but the boxes are not there. Happens both with dvips and pdflatex.

By changing the `hyperref` options, I can make the link texts colored, but cannot make the boxes visible. Thinking that MacTeX changed the default, I tried `[hidelinks=false]`, but the compiler says "unusual option for `hyperref`, ignored".

Any idea what happened and how I could get the boxes back?

I doubt that this is relevant, but besides `hyperref`, I'm also calling the following packages:

```
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,mathrsfs}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{psfig}
\input epsf.sty
\input labelfig.tex
\usepackage{showlabels}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{psfrag}
```

Comment: `psfig` and `epsf.sty` ??? was this document written in 1989?????

Comment: Thanks to Werner for beautifying the question. Regarding @DavidCarlisle 's question, no, it wasn't, although the person I learnt this from, probably started using LaTeX around that time. What am I "supposed" to use instead?

Comment: The displaying of the boxes is dependent on the PDF viewer. See [no border around hyperlinks with hyperref](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/210640/no-border-around-hyperlinks-with-hyperref/210777#210777).

Comment: BTW, `hidelinks` is not a boolean option, it does not take a value. The option is available since version 2011-02-05 v6.82a.